# Can one break a secury manager with sun.misc.unsafe?

Tags: java, security, classloader

Following a conversation on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761519/can-a-secret-be-hidden-in-a-safe-java-class-offering-access-credentials), an interesting issue is being raised.

Classes loaded with a security manager are protected with the corresponding security. This security could disable reflection (for example).

The question is: is it possible to break a security manager with sun.misc.unsafe? If yes, how?

**EDIT**

Changed `SecuredClassLoader` to Security Manager in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The `sun.misc.Unsafe` class requires an access check just like any other privileged action. You can block it with a custom class loader or security manager. Here's a simple example with an empty security manager that shows it'll throw an `AccessControlException`:

```
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
Unsafe unsafe = Unsafe.getUnsafe();
```

Comment: The guy forgot to mention that the code is executed on end user's (potentially hacker's) machine. I believe it changes the whole game... a bit ;)

Comment: Yeah, I agree that changes the whole game. I'm just answering this specific question and leaving that other part to the other question :)

Comment: @road to yamburg So, we've established that the situation is not the same when one is running code on a controlled server and a desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

What is "secure class loader"? SecureClassLoader? It is not secure, despite its name. All it does is limits the class loading source to a specific code location.

Therefore you don't even need any unsafe operations to "break" that. Just, for instance, make sure a replacement hacked class is in the classpath before SecureClassLoader even got the control.

Someone in that thread told you already -- you cannot have a secured spot in unsecured environment. If your code is deployed to a user machine, user is God there, and no JVM security can help you simply because JVM is a tiny layer on top of much more powerful native things.

Comment: Even if the machine has Trusted Computing facilities like memory curtaining, etc.? ;-) (Oh wait. No JVM implementation I know of employs any TC features.)

Comment: And a platoon of paratroopers over the user shoulders? Nay, Java has no this feature yet too! :D

Comment: I have edited the question. You are raising a great point about the hacked class in the class path + deployment on user machine.