# Do private fields provide any practical security?

Tags: java, security, reflection, private-members

Since we can access anything with reflection, no matter if it's a field, method or constructor, what does declaring something private really help/do? Is the sole purpose of a private field to tell other programmers that hey, this field isn't intended to be used like this?

While talking about security, is there a way to prevent users from accessing an API's (for the sake of the topic let's say it's closed-source) private and protected fields?

Comment: Access modifiers aren't really about security, they serve encapsulation.

Comment: Then where can I get security from?

Comment: You seem to be security confusing with API design. There is no way to stop a user from accessing an API unless you are running code on a JVM you control.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja, please define "security" in the context of your program.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Security as in not allowing private fields be accessed in any way outside of the class that holds the private fields. There is no program that spawned this question, it's just my general curiosity.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja, since you're curious, check out [Joe-E](https://code.google.com/p/joe-e/) which makes `private` mean what you want it to mean for code that passes the Joe-E verifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allow untrusted code to run in a JVM without a security manager, it can turn off `private` checking via [`setAccessible`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638826/java-reflection-impact-of-setaccessibletrue) thus making `private` fields and methods available via reflection.

Java's `SecurityManager` has a [poor history of withstanding determined attacks](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/08/30/how-turn-off-java-browser/) so it is not reasonable to assume that `SecurityManager` will prevent a determined attacker who can cause arbitrary bytecode to load.

Even if the `SecurityManager` holds up, proofs of concept have shown how secrets have been extracted via low-level Java APIs like the serialization API.

[Can a secret be hidden in a 'safe' java class offering access credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761519/can-a-secret-be-hidden-in-a-safe-java-class-offering-access-credentials) lists some of the pitfalls with trying to store sensitive data in fields in a JVM that also runs untrusted code.